# Is there a way to enable Java only for specific applications?

Tags: macos, security, java

I know that it is possible to [completely disable Java in OS X](http://markratledge.com/2012/04/disabling-java-on-os-x/), and to disable its use from [within a given browser](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5241). I use just one or two applications that require Java, and would like to enable it for them, but prevent it from running in all other cases.

Is there a way to enable Java only for certain apps that I specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but it's convoluted and non-intuitive.  I will say that I do not recommend this approach, but I am listing it for completeness.

[Java Default Policy Administration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) is the official doc on Java's own internal security and access policy.

The idea is that you can set deny access to files/folders at a global level, then add specific grant permissions to those Java classes/jars you want to allow.

The permission's that can be set are listed in the [JDK Permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html)

Some examples of what can be done can be found at [ExampleDepot](http://www.exampledepot.com/taxonomy/term/204)